# Extra space is appearing in right of my website

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a website with bootstrap and simple css

But there's some extra appearing on right of website, I have tried to solve it with overflow-x hidden
it solved my problem, but It makes a bad effect on my bootstrap navbar, so I decided not to apply this fix.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.static-cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.about {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orangered;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>About - GlobalAdmissionCycle</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GlobalAdmissionCycle.com</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active static-cool-link" href="#">About </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">|</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Overseas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Colleges</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section class="about">
    </section>
    
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my html code -

**Please someone tell me why is this extra space is appearing in my website  .**

Comment: with the code you provided the issue is not visible.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan actually it is visible, run the snippet in full screen.

Comment: Just tried on chrome 88.0.4324.96/MacOs on 1920x1080: I can't see any extra white space on the right or horizontal scrollbar. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: 100vw` on `.about` is causing the extra white space on the right of your website.

You can change it to `width: 100%` which removes the issue.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.static-cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.about {
  width: 100%; /* <------------- change this */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orangered;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>About - GlobalAdmissionCycle</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GlobalAdmissionCycle.com</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active static-cool-link" href="#">About </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">|</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Overseas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Colleges</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section class="about">
    </section>
    
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal scrollbar (extra space in the right of the page) is appearing because `width:100vw` is included vertical scrollbar width.

**[Viewport-percentage Lengths Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)**

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However, when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll bars are assumed not to exist. Note that the initial containing block’s size is affected by the presence of scrollbars on the viewport.

**Solution 1**

Remove `width:100vw` and add `width:100%` to `.about`

**Solution 2**

add `max-width:100%;` to `.about`

**Solution 3**

Add `overflow-x:hidden` to **body**/**parent container**

Answer (score 0):

Extra space due to you use "height: 100vh" with navbar

```
**.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 59px);
  background-color: orangered;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

change your **width** to **100%** from **100vw** in about class

```
.about {
    width: 100%;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change width to 100% in .about class. You can also add css to scrollbar to have a better look

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.static-cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orangered;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* css for scrollbar*/

.sbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.sbar::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.sbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(190, 52, 8, 1);
    background-color: orangered;
}
.scrollbar
{
scrollbar-face-color: #e36714;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #fff;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #fff;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #fff;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #fff;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #fff;
scrollbar-track-color: #fff;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>About - GlobalAdmissionCycle</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GlobalAdmissionCycle.com</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active static-cool-link" href="#">About </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">|</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Overseas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active cool-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Colleges</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section class="about">
    </section>
    
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```